# Using SelectSingleNode to locate an element with certain attribute value

Tags: xml, vb.net

Here is basic XML:

```
<WeekendMeeting Date="2020-04-05" StartTime="10:00" Title="Weekend Meeting" EventDuration="105" Included="true" AwayTalksAssigned="false" CircuitVisit="false">
    <Location>Text</Location>
    <Assignments>
        <Chairman> </Chairman>
        <Hospitality> </Hospitality>
        <Interpreter> </Interpreter>
        <Misc> </Misc>
    </Assignments>
    <HomeTalk>
        <Speaker>To Be Arranged</Speaker>
        <Congregation>Text</Congregation>
        <Theme>Text</Theme>
    </HomeTalk>
    <WatchtowerStudy>
        <Conductor> </Conductor>
        <Reader> </Reader>
        <Theme>We Will Go With You</Theme>
    </WatchtowerStudy>
</WeekendMeeting>
```

Now, I have this VB.Net code:

```
Dim nodeWeekend As XmlNode = nodeWeek.SelectSingleNode("WeekendMeeting")
If (Not nodeWeekend Is Nothing) Then
    sEvent = CreateEventMWBWeekend(nodeWeekend, sEventSettings, strEventType, bCreated)
    If (bCreated) Then
        ' Add the weekend event to the Google Calendar
        If (Not AddEventToCalendar(strEventType, sEvent, sEventSettings, strCalendarID, oBatchRequest)) Then
        End If
    End If
End If
```

The above code works, but as soon as I change it to use:

`Dim nodeWeekend As XmlNode = nodeWeek.SelectSingleNode("WeekendMeeting[@Included='true']")`

It does not work. It find no elements. Why? From what i can tell i am passing the correct xpath.

Comment: @preciousbetine Thanks for the suggestion but it doesn't seem to work doing that.

Comment: How about this `Dim nodeWeekend As XmlNode = nodeWeek.SelectSingleNode("/WeekendMeeting[@Included='true']")`

Comment: @preciousbetine No, using that `/` stops it from finding elements.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that my VB.Net is using `1` for `true` so I had to use:

`Dim nodeWeekend As XmlNode = nodeWeek.SelectSingleNode("WeekendMeeting[@Included='1']")`